# How to update sqlite database stored on network share by using an Android device

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have scoured the Google for this with not much hope.

Background:
I have a piece of software that runs natively on Windows. It reads/writes to a network shared SQLite database. There is a (remote)chance for several reads at once. NO chance of more than one write attempt at a time.

Is it possible to read/write to this database from an Android device? I have seen several concerns on db corruption. They all seem to relate to file locking/concurrent write issues. The nature of this software limits it to only one user writing at a time.

I can think of two options:

1. Write directly to the database from Android.
2. Use the Android device to only read the database, storing a local record of the changes. Upon return to the Windows software, use said software to "import" any changes made.

I can give details of the exact usage intended if it would help.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a programming issue but a workflow one in my opinion. I would either create a network endpoint (API) which would receive write requests, put them in a queue and then write one by one, or your 2nd option seems feasible.

Comment: It is most likely not possible to write directly to a remote database from an Android phone (nor would you want it).